# PHP MySQL select 2 columns where 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to select * from table1 where forename, surname = 'Joe Bloggs'

obviously forename and surname are 2 different columns in table one but im getting errors when i run this SQL code:

```
SELECT * from table1 where forename, surname = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

Any ideas on what i can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you mean

```
SELECT * from table1 where CONCAT_WS(' ',forename, surname) = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

OR

```
SELECT * from table1 where 'Joe Bloggs' IN (forename, surname)
```

OR

```
SELECT * from table1 where forename = 'Joe' AND surname = 'Bloggs'
```

Comment: i used the first one using CONCAT

Comment: @charliejsford next time when you ask a question, be sure to state the problem clearly and the things you need `:)`